# Remove Leading Spaces in Excel Address List

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have numerous files where the address field is in a single line of text, for the most part separated by a comma. My first step is using 'Replace' function in Excel to replace comma's with a carriage return. This is to turn an address from a single line into multiple lines.

The issue I'm looking to get assistance with, is when I complete the steps above, a leading space is often remaining in all rows from the second row onwards. I would like to know the best way to remove the leading spaces in these rows and keep the format of multi-line addresses.

I have tried using TRIM however these returns the address back to a single line

To show the pre and post transformed data I've added an image below as I can't seem to get the format to show correctly here on this post. Due to my profile being new I also can't imbed the image so there is a link below showing the pre and post transformed data, and the leading space issue I'm seeking help with

[Pre and Post Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnMYN.png)

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: You may want to replace “[comma][space]” instead of just “[comma]” with [carriage return]

Comment: So simple but you're spot on, that works. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: No worries. To cover both cases you can also try to nest it in one formula: first replace with [space] then wrap around a second replacement without [space]

Answer (score 0):

As @Anonymous mention in comment, replace both comma and space at a time by `SUBSTITUTE()` formula and use `WRAP TEXT` format of resulting cell.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ",CHAR(10))
```

[image]